# net::ERR_ABORTED 4 getting this error in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

while using **Link** component in **nextJs**

```
<Link href={getRouteByName('my-plan')} prefetch>
          <a className="btn btn-md ">Know More</a>
```

in my `routes.js` :

```
const Pages = {
    '/my-plan': {
        page: '/my-plan-data',
    }
}
```

so as per logic it should only redirect to `/my-plan-data` component..but first its tries to load `my-plan.js` file which is not there so i am getting error:

```
https://www.abc.co.net/_next/static/cs9IaQX_VQGgxiz6rnlSO/pages/my-plan.js net::ERR_ABORTED 4
```

and then its reload that component.
Kindly please help me how to resolve this issue